# List total number of build along with sucess and failed builds on Jenkins

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, groovy, scripting

I would like to monitor how many builds had run since last day with shell or groovy scripts.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: You can use the [Jenkins Remote API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API). Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25648908/172599

Comment: Thanks @Dave for the help.